# Haskell: Parse error pattern using ValTypes

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, parse-error

Can someone please explain why I keep getting this error? Especially when a different module, on the same laptop, can run the same expression and it be fine?

```
minCompare :: ValType -> ValType -> ValType
minCompare leftSide rightSide
     leftSide == rightSide = leftSide
     leftSide < rightSide = leftSide
     otherwise = rightSide
```

[Haskell code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAUlB.png)

Comment: Please paste the code as text in your question. Images are less accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close!  You are just missing the guard symbol `|` before the conditions.

```
minCompare :: ValType -> ValType -> ValType
minCompare leftSide rightSide
    | leftSide == rightSide = leftSide
    | leftSide < rightSide = leftSide
    | otherwise = rightSide
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't have to use pattern matching, if else should be enough. Your syntax for function and pattern matching is slightly off. (That happens to any new haskell beginner quite often)

```
import Data.Ord


minCompare :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
minCompare left right = if left >= right then left else right

minCompare' :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
minCompare' left right = case (compare left right) of
                            LT -> right
                            EQ -> left
                            GT -> left

minCompare'' :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
minCompare'' left right = case (compare left right) of
                            LT -> right
                            _ -> left
```